# Merge data from specific range of all sheets in a folder to a master sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Do I have script that I am trying to get a specific range (single row ie AB2:AB10) from each sheet in a folder (getfolderbyid("jkhkkkkkkk") to copy to a specific master sheet getsheetbyID("lklklkjllj")

this is what I have but it is looping through all 5000 row of the source data sheet so is very slow
///////////////////////////////////////////
function getGaccountsDatafrom() {

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID");
 var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();


 *var file;
 var fileType;
 var ssID;
 var combinedData = [];
   var data;
 while(filesIterator.hasNext()){
 file = filesIterator.next();
  fileType = file.getMimeType();  
  if(fileType ==="application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
  ssID = file.getId();
  data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
 combinedData = combinedData.concat(data);
  } //if end here
 }// while ends here
 var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA");
ws.getRange("A2:AQ").clearContent();
ws.getRange(2, 1, combinedData.length, combinedData[0].length).setValues(combinedData);
 }
 function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
 var ws = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
 var data = ws.getRange("CG3:DW3"+ ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
 return data;
  }////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... the code is not "looping through all 5000 row of the source data sheet" but iterating files in a folder and getting data from each file separately. That is what makes it run slow, and I do not know if it can be made much faster.

The `getDataFromSpreadsheet()` function gets too much data because of the superfluous `3` so the result will have blank rows in between. Here is a quick fix:

```
  const data = ws.getRange('CG3:DW' + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
```